# Appending elements to a parent element inside arr.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a loop that will append a child div to a parent div based on each element from an array.  I have attempted to create a parent element and append child nodes to the parent.  My thought is I can iterate over an array and for each element I can append a new child element.

```
function createHtmlChildElems(arr){
  var list= document.createElement('div');
  var item= document.createElement('div');
  list.innerHTML = '';

  //iterate over my array and append something for each element in the array
  $.each(arr, function(index,element){  
    item.innerHTML=`index: ${index}` 
    list.appendChild(item);

  });
  return list;
}
```

List returns only the parent element that contains one childnode.  For example, if passing in a three element array, I would expect the result to include
    'index: 0'
    'index: 1'
    'index: 2'

but it only contains 'index: 2'

Comment: Also you're only creating one item.  If you change `meal` to `item` you're going to be changing the same item over and over.  The item creation needs to be in the loop

Comment: sorry about that, i renamed the vars for the example.  In my code the variable name matches, I have updated accordingly

Comment: I needed to create it in the loop, if you submit a response I will mark as answer when I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you declare a single `item` div, and update it in each iteration. To append multiple elements you need to create new `div` instances within the loop:

```js
function createHtmlChildElems(arr) {
  var list = document.createElement('div');
  list.innerHTML = '';

  arr.forEach(function(element, index) {
    var item = document.createElement('div');
    item.innerHTML = `index: ${index}`
    list.appendChild(item);
  });
  return list;
}

var foo = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var elems = createHtmlChildElems(foo);
document.querySelector('div').append(elems);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Note that I changed the `$.each()` call to a plain `forEach()` so you don't need the jQuery dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

You're only creating one item.  You need to create multiple.  Also this logic is where you can use `map()`

```
function createHtmlChildElems(arr){
  var $list = $('<div>');

  $list.append(
    $.map(arr, function(index, element){
      return `<div>index: ${index}</div>`;
    });
  );

  return $list;
}
```